# Creating invoice backend works but gives blank screen Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, invoice, backend, create-invoice

Every time I create an Invoice from Sales Order it gives me Blank screen (see attached) even though it's blank screen the invoice was created but not visible.

[image]

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any error log in var folder?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProductUrl() on a non-object in /home/joliefi/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml on line 31